# How to put a dot after reference number in plainnat

Tags: natbib

In plainnat I have got something like this:
[image]

But I need to put a dot after the number of the reference and some space, i.e. something like this:

[image]

Can you help me?

MWE:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\large \textbf{REFERENCES}}
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand{\@biblabel}{\hfill}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in justo orci. 
Phasellus pharetra elit sit amet lobortis pretium. Donec a tortor est. In 
pretium imperdiet erat ut egestas. Vestibulum pellentesque erat augue, quis 
facilisis lorem lobortis ac. Suspendisse a magna lacinia, pretium nisl sit 
amet, blandit ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam at porta ex, non 
condimentum lectus \citep{esry2007}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs.bib}%

\end{document}
```

refs.bib:

```
@article{esry2007,
    title = {General Theory of Carrier-Envelope Phase Effects},
    author = {Roudnev, V. and Esry, B. D.},
    journal = PRL,
    volume = {99},
    number = {22},
    pages = {220406},
    year = {2007},
    publisher = {APS}
}
```

I also copied the plainnat.bst file from CTAN. I may give reference if you like.

Comment: That bit of the bibliography formatting is usually not controlled by the BibTeX style you use (`plainnat`) but by your document class and by the bibliography-related packages you load. If you want good help quickly, your best bet is to create a short yet compilable example document that shows how you generate your bibliography at the moment. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.

Comment: I've tried to do what you asked @moewe. Hope that would help?

Comment: Please do share the following piece of information: the document class you employ.

Comment: I have shared it. @Mico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sufficient to properly redefine `\@biblabel`. You may want to change `3em` to any other length you see fit.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,turkish]{babel}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\begin{center}\large \textbf{REFERENCES}\end{center}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\makebox[3em][l]{#1.}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in justo orci. 
Phasellus pharetra elit sit amet lobortis pretium. Donec a tortor est. In 
pretium imperdiet erat ut egestas. Vestibulum pellentesque erat augue, quis 
facilisis lorem lobortis ac. Suspendisse a magna lacinia, pretium nisl sit 
amet, blandit ligula. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam at porta ex, non 
condimentum lectus \citep{esry2007}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much!